# How to get an iMessage conversation to go back from green to blue?

Tags: iphone, ios, messages, sms

After some overseas travel my imessage conversation with my contact (also an iPhone user) switched from blue (iMessage) to green (SMS) - due to problems with international roaming.

We're back in our home country, but the message conversation persists in SMS (green) and we'd like it to go back to iMessage (blue). I don't know how to click it back over.

My question is: **How to get an iMessage conversation to go back from green to blue?**

Comment: Try temporarily turning off **Settings** > **Messages** > **Send as SMS**. Then send some messages.  It their back to blue you can turn **Send as SMS** back on and sent additional messages to ensure they're still blue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Settings

Before doing anything:

1. **Quit** the **Messages app** (Double press your home button and swipe up on the Messages app).
2. Go to **Settings** > **Messages** and Turn **OFF** and then back **ON** your iMessage option.
3. Now **open** back **Message** and try to send a message to your friend 's iPhone, but make sure to use the button at the Top-Left corner to find your friend and start the conversation, don't just open your recent chat with him/her.

This should have reset your iMessage settings, so you should be able to send iMessages to your friend now.

---

## Restart

If the process above didn't solve the issue, you may want to:

1. **Restart** your iPhone, long press the Sleep/Wake button until you see the Apple logo again, then release, OR you can long press until you see a slider which can be used to turn OFF the iPhone, once done that, press again the Sleep/Wake button to turn the iPhone back ON.
2. Try to **send** a message to your friend

   ---

I'm sure you already know the difference between iMessage and normal SMS/MMS, although that, I'll leave you a link to the [Apple Support page](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201287) about the difference, have a great day!

Answer (score 2):

I read many comments to try and solve my inability to use iMessages with my friend, They all overlooked what my problem was. I turned iMessages on and off in Settings, restarted my iPhone 7 and deleted the entire past message thread between us.
The problem was, there are two ends to a message. My friend simply didn't have iMessage turned on on his end.

Answer (score 1):

- Close your Messages app (double click the home button then swipe from bottom to top on the app)
- Restart your phone.
- After the phone boots back up, open Messages.
- Initiate a message to the other person via the Compose button.

Restart your iPhone by holding the Sleep/Wake button until you see a slider. Slide to shutdown your phone and wait until it is fully powered off before powering it back up.

Answer (score 1):

Send a photo or attach a screenshot to the message. That pushes data through the pipe and will show you that the iMessage network refreshes. This usually fixes the issue.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/166542)

Comment: If you send a photo or an attachment in a message it solves the issue. ie messages go from SMS back to iMessage (blue)

Answer (score 0):

Delete all messages in your feed to the effected 
person that were sent via SMS.
Then the green send arrow will be blue (just like it was when you 
originally sent the current message).

Answer (score 0):

Delete the conversation that has text messages messaging. Create a new conversation. Basically, replacing it. This is of course, a 'last resort' kind of option.